# CHANGING the text of a button with SHARED PREFERENCES android studio

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-button

I'm making a simple app that has a button. When a pokemon is caught, I want the text to be "release" and when it's not, to be "catch!". When clicking the button, I want to change caught from true to false or vice-versa.

For now, i've done this (it doesn't work as I expected):

```
    public void toggleCatch(View view) {

        boolean caught;

        String name = nameTextView.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences captured = getSharedPreferences("pokemon_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (captured.contains (name) ){
            catch_button.setText("Release");
            caught=true;
        }
        else{
            catch_button.setText("Catch!");
            caught=false;
        }

        if (caught) {
            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("pokemon_name", name).commit();
        } else {
            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(name).commit();
        }

    }
```

I would be very thankful if someone can help me!

*I'm lost so I don't know if I'm on the correct path, my code is probably completely wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess here is what you want:

In your app, you have an `EditText` that allows users to input pokemon name. When users click on the toggle catch button,

- If the pokemon name is captured (the pokemon name has been saved in the `SharePreferences`), then remove the pokemon name from the `SharePreferences` and set the text of the button to "Release".
- If the pokemon name is not captured (the pokemon name hasn't been saved in the `SharePreferences`), then add the pokemon name to the `SharePreferences` and set the text of the button to "Catch!".

**Solution**

```
public void toggleCatch(View view) {
    String name = nameTextView.getText().toString().trim();
    SharedPreferences captured = getSharedPreferences("pokemon_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean caught = captured.contains(name);
    if (caught) {
        captured.edit().remove(name).apply();
        catch_button.setText("Release");
    } else {
        captured.edit().putBoolean(name, true).apply();
        catch_button.setText("Catch!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences is a map of `key-value` pairs. So if you are trying to access the value you should check whether the key exists which in your case is `pokemon_name`.

```
if (captured.contains("pokemon_name")){
    ...
}
```

And when removing once again you should give the key, not the value.

```
...edit().remove("pokemon_name").commit();
```

---

Read [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) official documentation to understand better.